# For iScroll, how to get items in the veiwport

Tags: iscroll

I have a div for iScroll as below, I want to get the items in the current viewport while scrolling, how can I do this? pls help me, thank you advance.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id='a'>A</li>
    <li id='b'>B</li>
    <li id='c'>C</li>
    <li id='d'>D</li>
    <li id='e'>E</li>
    <li id='f'>F</li>
    <li id='g'>G</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```